# Programar en R, la función buscar de excel

Tags: r

estoy validando unos cálculos de una hoja de excel en R. Existe una columna de excel que hace unos cálculos con la función BUSCAR, al implemetar una función similar en R, tengo que los resultados son similares, a excepción del primer dato. Quisiera saber como me pueden asesorar para replicar los mismos resultados de la función en R.
A continuación les dejo el código.

```
buscar<-function(x,A,U){
#'x->Número a buscar
#'A->Vector a Comparar
#'U->Vector que contine el valor a entrega
i=0; u_sist=0
for(i in seq_along(A)){
  if(A[i]==x){
    u_sist=U[i]/2
  }
  if(A[i]<x){
    u_sist=U[i]/2
  }
  if(A[i]>x){
    u_sist=U[i-1]/2
  }
  
}
return(u_sist)
```

}

Comment: Y no es más rápido si usas un join?

Comment: ¿Pero que es lo que esperas que haga tu función o más bien que tiene que ver con la función buscar de excel? ¿qué hacen esas divisiones por 2?

Comment: Una función `buscar` de excel en R sería algo así: `U[which(x == A)[1]]`